How can I enable fade in alpha animation for a drawable?
I want to apply an alpha animation to a drawable. The code is like the screenshot below. The animation doesn't exist and the drawable icon shows up immediately.

I also tried to update color of the drawable something like the following code, but it also doesn't work.

Does someone know if drawable can have an alpha animation if I want to set it to ImageSpan and SpannableString? Thanks!

Maybe just set Drawable in the ImageView and animate the ImageView?
For example like this:
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, your_drawable_res))

imageView.alpha = 0f
imageView.animate()
             .alpha(1f)
             .setDuration(3000)
             .start()

